# How to structure a threaded TCP client in Java

Tags: java, tcpclient

I need to write a threaded TCP client in Java but am unsure about how to best structure it. I would like the client to run on another thread so as to not block the main thread.

Ideally I would create the client on the main thread and then instruct the client to connect to the server. The connecting which may take some time would happen on another thread. Once the client has connected, it would notify the main thread and start listening for incoming messages from the server. The main thread is notified as messages are received.

At the moment my plan is to have a TCP client class implement Runnable and perform both the connecting and receiving in the run method.

I'd appreciate any thoughts on how to structure the tcp client.

Comment: Question 1. Is it a GUI application or a command-line application or e.g. a non-iteractive part of some bigger system?

Comment: Question 2. What would You mean by "notify the main thread"?

Comment: Question 3. Could you give some more detail of what kind of protocol is it; and how the messages are to be going back-and-forth?

Comment: Question 4. How complicated and robust is it going to be? Maybe it's just a do-simple-stuff-and-quit kind ?

Comment: It's a command line application. Automated with no user. Once connected, the client will receive messages from the server for as long as it is connected. It can also send messages to the server.

By notify I mean the client reports it state. Possibly by calling a method on the object which created it updating a state variable. The main thread could then act on the change of state.

Comment: What kind of messages? What is the "main thread" doing?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the things which you should consider while structurinng Your application:
1. Ideally, there should be separate threads for reading and writing the network streams. Otherwise there may be problems. 
2. If You want to "inform" other threads about something or pass something, consider the Java "Condition" idiom/object and/or the blocking Queues/Deques.

Comment: I use java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque to queue things which are going to be sent via network.

Comment: Something which can also help You: a sketch of a "state machine" ( kinda like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_machine ) of your system.

Comment: Please upvote the answer (the up-arrow) if you find it somewhat helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JBoss Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) and handle the communication between the Threads with a [Queue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) implementation that fits your needs.

Netty has a steer learning curve, but it pays of with a easy maintainable design and as long you dont need UDP transfer (then i would take a look at [Apache Mina](http://mina.apache.org)) it's just enough. Also you don't need to implement a State Machine with Netty.